# Using ncdu, how to know the number of items in current dir, not total count in childtree

Tags: linux, macos, du

I love using **ncdu** to browse files in Debian (and also MacOS), yet I can't figure out a way to display the number of items in the current directory, rather than the total amount of files including all the children directories.

I read the manual using `man ncdu` on both Debian and MacOS.

Comment: `ncdu` is designed to show sub-folders. You should really look for another product.

Comment: @harrymc mmm... not sure I understand your suggestion. I'd like to show sub-folders in a "gui", so ncdu does exactly the job. While browsing using ncdu, I'd like to get some valuable additional information, like the number of items (files and folders) in the current dir, namely `.`, or any other dir listed in a given ncdu display.

Comment: See [ncdu alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/ncdu/?platform=linux). It's not the only one of its kind.

Comment: Will do, thanks. Seems like `duf`is the only option meeting my main requirement ("terminal-based" gui)